# SQLite foreign key design issue

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

I have table `points` with fields

```
id(primary key), lat, lon
```

Also `cctv_cams` table

```
  cctv_id(primary key), point_id, name
```

and lastly `speeding_cams` table

```
speeding_id(primary key), point_id_a, point_id_b, name
```

each, `cctv_cams` and `speeding_cams` have their own set of points. They don't share same points. 
One `cctv_cams` row can refer to many `points` rows. `cctv_cams` row can't exist if it has no corresponding `points`.

I tried to setup foreign keys, so when I delete `cctv_cams`, then all corresponding `points` will be also deleted. It looks like I have to define foreign key in all tables to accomplish this?

**Update:** Description for redesigning table

Point itself is not one row, but series of rows in `points` table. For one logical point I insert many points and all that points in series should be identified as 1 point.
There are 3 sources that should refer to such series of points.

1. `cctv_cams` table
2. `speeding_cams` table for **point A**
3. `speeding_cams` table for **point B**

Back to cascading - when I delete speeding cam record for example, all series of point A and B should be deleted as well from `points` table. Same for cctv cam record.

Comment: I fear the scope of the question has changed dramatically. You might have a design issue going on that's entirely separate. I suggest you get the design straight first (look into a data modeling software maybe, like OpenModelSphere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you need to define the tables which have foreign keys thus:

```
CREATE TABLE cctv_cams (
cctv_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
point_id INTEGER,
name TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY (point_id) REFERENCES points(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

And that will cause a deletion in `points` to cause the elements of `cctv_cams` to be deleted. For the other way around, for a deletion in `cctv_cams` to cause the corresponding `points` entry to be erased, you should define a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER points_cctv_cams_Trigger AFTER DELETE ON cctv_cams
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM points WHERE id = old.point_id);
END;
```

As for one row of `cctv_cams` having more than one entry of `points`, your definitions really don't indicate that. One row is one row. Maybe you need to revise your schema?

---

Further information on foreign keys:

To check if foreign key support is enabled, use:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys;
```

To make sure it is enabled, use:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

You'll need to set that every time you connect. The only way not to have to do it every time is if SQLite was compiled with neither `SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY` or `SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER`. Because this can change depending where you got your copy from, check your `foreign_keys` value. If your version gives you ON, it's always going to be ON. Just remember: it's not dependent on the database, but on the engine.

Comment: I definitely need to redesign this. I'll update my post with new design shortly.

Comment: @Pablo Sounds like you need a cctv_cams_points junction table.

Comment: I need to explain data structure better, then you will see probably that I don't need junction table. I will try to explain shortly, give me a chance )

Comment: I've tried to explain details, plz let me know if you understand the logical schema otherwise I will give some examples.

Comment: well, for now I've just created 3 point tables, `points_cctv`, `points_spd_a`, `points_spd_b` and in each one there is a link to cctv and speeding tables accordingly. However, most of the data in those `point_*` tables are redundant...